# Run exe file while it is still open in C#

Tags: c#, file, process, shared

Currently I do the following:

1. Include an EXE file in resource file.
2. in runtime I extract EXE file and write it to a file on HDD, with "DeleteOnClose" option.
3. Obviously II do not close the file so it remains on Disk.
4. I go to path and double click it , but it refuses to open.
5. if I use "Process.Start" I get file not exist error although it is there in the given path.
6. I set FileShare and FileAccess to ReadWrite.
7. Again Process.Start doesn't work.

Here is the code I use:

```
byte[] exeFile =ExeSecure.Properties.Resources.ReqCheck;
//2) Create file to be deleted on close
FileStream aFile = new FileStream(@"c:\reco.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 20000, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
//3) Write Exe file content to HDD
aFile.Write(exeFile, 0, exeFile.Length);
aFile.Flush();
Thread.Sleep(100); //Wait a while for file to be flushed
while (!File.Exists(@"c:\reco.exe")); //Make sure file is there on HDD
    Process.Start("C:\reco.exe");//Start file , this always fails.
```

Comment: Not related but I would've add some delay in your while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is just a typo in your question, but the path in `Process.Start` is incorrect. You are missing the `@` sign:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\reco.exe");
```

Comment: First time I hear about `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`. I don't see any usage of it....(am I wrong?)? it basically means that the file must have .flush be called in order to make it a whole file , and then use it while not closing it.isn't it weird ?

Comment: The point is as long as the file is open from C# code , you can never double click it in windows and get it to run , also you can't execute it using Process.Start() , and the option to delete the file on close is very useful if you launch some exe from your resources and want them to be deleted after you are finished with them , so you instruct Windows to do so with this option.